# Python analyzing computer-vision output

Tags: python, list, dictionary, computer-vision, list-comprehension

through a computer-vision program and object recognition I get arrays like this, which describes rectangles around the recognized objects:

```
[{
  min: { x: 0.04963243, y: 0.48638576 },
  max: { x: 0.31779325, y: 0.99719137 },
  object_class: {
    id: '1',
    class_number: '1',
    name: 'aaaa',
    confidence: 0.97399896
  }
},
{
  min: { x: 0.048526138, y: 0 },
  max: { x: 0.3132363, y: 0.4141748 },
  object_class: {
    id: '2',
    class_number: '2',
    name: 'bbbb'
    confidence: 0.7052338
  }
},
{
  min: { x: 0.05446595, y: 0 },
  max: { x: 0.31821355, y: 0.41463163 },
  object_class: {
    id: '1',
    class_number: '1',
    name: 'aaaa',
    confidence: 0.702788
  }
},
{
  min: { x: 0.043725803, y: 0.4907713 },
  max: { x: 0.31781, y: 0.9913551 },
  object_class: {
    id: '2',
    class_number: '2',
    name: 'bbbb',
    confidence: 0.6097382
  }
}]
```

I'm trying to get the **min** and **max** values to crop areas of the taken photos.
So I'm new to python and don't really know how I can do this. I looked into list comprehensions but don't see a way to implement it.

When I try to work with the array I also get the Error
`NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing commas between {} blocks?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I forgot them.

Comment: your data does not look like a valid python object, where does it come from?

Comment: I got the data for this task in a text file to write the script. I'm not really sure where the output comes from myself but it's not a python object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. I hope you know using for loops in python.

```
arr = [{
    'min': {'x': 0.04963243, 'y': 0.48638576},
    'max': {'x': 0.31779325, 'y': 0.99719137},
    'object_class': {
        'id': '1',
        'class_number': '1',
        'name': 'aaaa',
        'confidence': 0.97399896
    }
},
    {
    'min': {'x': 0.048526138, 'y': 0},
    'max': {'x': 0.3132363, 'y': 0.4141748},
    'object_class': {
        'id': '2',
        'class_number': '2',
        'name': 'bbbb', #mistake here comma missing
        'confidence': 0.7052338
    }
},
    {
    'min': {'x': 0.05446595, 'y': 0},
    'max': {'x': 0.31821355, 'y': 0.41463163},
    'object_class': {
        'id': '1',
        'class_number': '1',
        'name': 'aaaa',
        'confidence': 0.702788
    }
},
    {
    'min': {'x': 0.043725803, 'y': 0.4907713},
    'max': {'x': 0.31781, 'y': 0.9913551},
    'object_class': {
        'id': '2',
        'class_number': '2',
        'name': 'bbbb',
        'confidence': 0.6097382
    }
}]

# loop through your array
for i in arr:
    
    # min amount is obtained by i['min']
    min_amount = i['min']
    
    # max amount is obtained by i['max']
    max_amount = i['max']

    # check them out
    print(min_amount)
    print(max_amount)
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much, for your quick help :) 
I thought I can somehow do it without the ` ' ' `

Comment: you can use an integer, float, string, or boolean as a dictionary key. So you need quotations around dictionary keys unless they are variables. check out python docs